# Instruction inside a While Loop Matlab

Tags: matlab

What does this instruction `vector=[vector,sum(othervector)]` does in matlab inside a while loop like:

```
vector=[]; 

while a - b ~= 0
  othervector = sum(something') %returns a vector
  vector=[vector,sum(othervector)]; %it keeps a new vector?
  ...

end

vector=vector./100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Executing `a = [a,b]` means append `b` to `a`, thus `vector` will eventually be a matrix where each column is the row-wise sum of `something'`.

---

More concretely: suppose `something'` is this matrix:

```
something' = [ 1, 2; 3, 4 ];
```

Then `sum(something')` is:

```
othervector = [ 3 ; 7 ]
```

And initially `vector` is empty, so this sets `vector` to

```
vector = [ 3 ; 7 ]
```

Suppose we repeat with a new `something'` consisting of

```
[ 5, 5; 5, 6 ]
```

Then `sum(something')` is:

```
othervector = [ 10; 11 ]
```

And now we augment this to `vector` using `vector = [vector, sum(othervector)]`:

```
vector = [ vector, [10; 11] ] = [ 3, 10 ; 7, 11 ]
```